# Convert a list of floats to multiple columns of floats in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have in `pandas` a column that contains a list of 1000 `float`. But instead of having one column with a list, I would like to have 1000 columns of one `float`. Right now, these lists are stored with the `string` type.

Example of a list (cropped):

```
[0.12953150272369385, 0.16092558205127716, -0.03718775138258934]
```

I know it's possible to do it by iterating over the rows and creating 1000 columns and passing the new values one by one. But that would be slow.

Is there a faster way to do so?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame({"Col": [0.12953150272369385, 0.16092558205127716, -0.03718775138258934]})` ?

Answer (score 2):

Put it in brackets so that you have a list of the list:

```
l = [0.12953150272369385, 0.16092558205127716, -0.03718775138258934]

pd.DataFrame(l)
Out: 
          0
0  0.129532
1  0.160926
2 -0.037188

pd.DataFrame([l])
Out: 
          0         1         2
0  0.129532  0.160926 -0.037188
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple rows, with each row have a list of floats, then the best solution is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'floats': [[0.6, 0.3], [0.3, 0.4]]})
    floats
0   [0.6, 0.3]
1   [0.3, 0.4]

df = df.floats.apply(pd.Series)
    0   1
0   0.6 0.3
1   0.3 0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with [T](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) which transposes index and columns:

```
l = [0.12953150272369385, 0.16092558205127716, -0.03718775138258934]

df = pd.DataFrame(l)
df
#          0
#0  0.129532
#1  0.160926
#2 -0.037188
df.T
#          0         1         2
#0  0.129532  0.160926 -0.037188
```